# JavaScript: Can the Boolean object be used as a callback function?

Tags: javascript, callback, boolean, ecmascript-6

I would like to write `array.some(Boolean)` as a way to test if any elements in `array` are truthy.

Are there any issues with using the `Boolean` object in this way? Does it have the same behavior across modern browsers? Is it always equivalent to `array.some(function(elem) { return !!elem; })`?

Comment: As far as I know this function that casts any value to Boolean. Any function is also an object, so Boolean being an object should not be a problem.

Comment: Of course, somebody with a good sense of humor could overwrite the `Boolean` function with, say, `Boolean = function() { return true; };`. Besides that, there should be no contraindications.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Are there any issues with using the `Boolean` object in this way?

No. Unlike `parseInt` for example (which would be problematic), `Boolean` only expects a single argument. So there shouldn't be any issues with passing the other callback arguments to it (index and the array), it will simply ignore them.

> Does it have the same behavior across modern browsers?

I do hope so. If you can't trust the `Boolean` function, what else is left?

> Is it always equivalent to `array.some(function(elem) { return !!elem; })`?

Yes. From the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-boolean-constructor):

> When `Boolean` is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it performs a type conversion.

And that's essentially what `!!` does as well.

---

Relevant references from the spec:

- [`Boolean` function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-boolean-constructor)
- [`!` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-logical-not-operator)
- [(internal) `ToBoolean` function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-toboolean)